# Getting FieldError on confirm_ password when trying to create a custom user form

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a custom user creation form for username, password, and confirm password but I'm getting FieldError for `confirm_password`. The error goes away when I remove it from fields.

```
class RegForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'confirm_password')
        widgets = {
            'username': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={'class': 'form-control mb-4', 'required': True, 'placeholder': 'Username'}),
            'password': forms.PasswordInput(
                attrs={'class': 'form-control mb-4', 'required': True, 'placeholder': 'Password'}),
            'confirm_password': forms.PasswordInput(
                attrs={'class': 'form-control mb-4', 'required': True, 'placeholder': 'Confirm Password'}),
        }

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(RegForm, self).clean()
        password = cleaned_data.get("password")
        confirm_password = cleaned_data.get("confirm_password")

        if password != confirm_password:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "Passwords needs to match"
            )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Clean Like This:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
password=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
confirm_password=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
class Meta:
    model=User
    fields=('username','email','password')

def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(UserForm, self).clean()
    password = cleaned_data.get("password")
    confirm_password = cleaned_data.get("confirm_password")

    if password != confirm_password:
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            "password and confirm_password does not match"
        )
```

Comment: The clean method is fine. Everything else you had fixed it with some tweaks.